# Is the space $\ell^\infty$ a Hilbert space?

Tags: solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

> Is the space $\ell^\infty$ a Hilbert space?

I'm wondering if we can verify this using the parallelogram law? If $x = (1,0,0,\dots)$ and $y=(0,1,0,0, \dots)$ are both in $\ell^\infty$, then $$\|x+y\|^2_\infty = 1 \ne 2\|x\|^2_\infty + 2\|y\|^2_\infty = 4 $$

so this space does not satisfy the parallelogram law. Would this mean that space is not a Hilbert space if so why?

Comment: 1/ A Hilbert space is endowed with an inner product... if the $\ell^{\infty}$ norm induced by an inner product, then...

Comment: In order for a space to be a Hilbert space, it must be an inner product space and be complete wrt the metric induced by the inner product. In this case, the norm on $\ell^\infty$ is not induced by an inner product (since it doesn't satisfy the parallelogram law) and hence is not a Hilbert space. You can show however that for any $p\neq 2$ s.t $p>1$, $\ell^p$ is not a Hilbert space (with the $\|\cdot\|_p$ norm).

Comment: It shows that $\ell^\infty$ *for this norm* is not a Hilbert space yes, since if it were one, then the inner product induced by $||.||_\infty$ would satisfy the parallelogram law. (I do not know however if you can put another norm on this space such that it becomes a Hilbert space, if that is your question.)

Comment: 2/ show the Parallelogram Law $\|x+y \|^{2} + \|x-y \|^{2} = 2\|x \|^{2} + 2\|y \|^{2}$ using linearity of inner of products (assuming such exists).

Comment: I believe you can define a new norm such that $(\ell^{\infty}, \|.\|_{\mathrm{new}})$ is a Hilbert space (satisfies parallelogram law). It is definitely true when you have a countable basis (separable), and while $(\ell^{\infty}, \|.\|_{\infty})$ is not separable, I think it's also true in this case.

Comment: @ChristopherK: the issue is then whether the topology generated by $\|\;\|_\infty$ and $\|\;\|_{new}$ are equivalent.

Comment: For one example, I think the norm defined by $\lVert x \rVert_{new} := \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} |x_n|^2 \right)^{1/2}$ induces the product topology (pointwise convergence) rather than the $\ell^\infty$ topology (uniform convergence).

Comment: @OliverDíaz: good point!

Comment: @DanielSchepler: many thanks for the example!

Comment: @DanielSchepler: With that metric $\ell_\infty$ is actually contained in a larger Hilbert space $H$ and $\ell_\infty$ is not closed there.

Comment: I guess you're right, that metric isn't complete so it doesn't come from a Hilbert space.  I think the completion would be $\ell^2$, with the isometric embedding being $(x_n) \mapsto (2^{-n/2} x_n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long comment that I rather put in the answer section.

The space $(\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N}),\|\;\|_\infty)$ as the OP indicated is not a Hilbert space in the sense that the norm $\|\;\|_\infty$ is not induced by an inner product (the parallelogram identity does not hold)

It is possible to define an inner product on  $\ell_\infty$ so that, with the induced norm $\|\;\|$, $(\ell_\infty,\|\;\|)$ is a subspace of a  Hilbert space $H$, for example $\langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle =\sum_n a_nx_ny_n$, where $a_n>0$ and $\sum_na_n<\infty$. The Hilbert $H$ containing $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})$ is given by $H=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}:\sum_na_n |\mathbf{x}(n)|^2<\infty\}$.

Notice that the inclusion map $\iota:(\ell_\infty,\|\;\|_\infty)\rightarrow (H,\|\;\|)$ is bounded:
$$\|\mathbf{x}\|\leq\Big(\sum_na_n\Big)\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty$$
However the norms $\|\;\|$ and $\|\;\|_\infty$ are not equivalent  on $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})$, otherwise $\iota^{-1}:(\ell_\infty,\|;\|)\rightarrow(\ell_\infty,\|\;\|_\infty)$ would be a continuous linear operator and so there would be a constant $c>0$ such that $\|\mathbf{x}\|_\infty\leq c\|\mathbf{x}\|$.
This means $(\ell_\infty,\|\;\|_\infty)$ and $(\ell_\infty,\|;\|)$ would have the same Cauchy sequences. This is not the case however: the sequence $\mathbf{e}_m:n\mapsto\mathbb{1}_{\{1,\ldots,m\}}(n)$ is Cauchy in $(\ell_\infty,\|\;\|)$   but not in $(\ell_\infty,\|\;\|_\infty)$.

The question is whether any such norm $\|\;\|$ induced the same topology as that induced by $\|\;\|_\infty$.
The key point, I think, is to notice that under $\|\;\|_\infty$, $\ell_\infty$ is not separable. Under the inner product above, $\ell_\infty$ becomes separable.

The solution to the OP would follow if one proves

> Suppose $\|\;\|$ is a norm on $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N})$ that is induced by an inner product. Then $(\ell_\infty(\mathbb{N}), \|\;\|)$ is separable.

I have not checked the details, but It seems to be true.